# JQuery datepicker resets past dates to current date if the text box having past dates and datepicker having minDate:0

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to disable selecting past dates from jquery datepicker and if the text box having past dates it should be like that only.

I wrote code like the following,

```
$("#t1").datepicker({
      minDate:0
});
```

text box code,

```
<input type="t1" value="13/09/12">
```

Now when the datepicker activated, the text box value setting to current date. I don't want to set like that and at the same date picker should not show past date.

Answer (score 0):

probably you have to validate beforeShowDay, try this:

```
            function checkDate(date) {
            var specificdate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            var nowdate = new Date();
            if (date >= nowdate || specificdate - date == 0) {
                return [true, ""];
            } else {
                return [false, "unavailable", "unavailable"];
            }
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#t1").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                setDate:  $(this).val(),
                beforeShowDay: checkDate
            });

        });
```

Comment: i want to display textbox value as it is.

Comment: I have modifed response, please look if it meet your demands.